# URL parameters and stylesheets in Blazor .NET 8

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, .net-8.0

I have a Blazor Web application project on .NET 8 with `autorendering`. In the client project I've created a page with page parameters like this:

**Html:**

```
@page "/"
@page "/{parent?}"
@page "/{parent?}/{categoryUrl?}"
@page "/{parent?}/{categoryUrl?}/{url?}"
@page "/{parent?}/{categoryUrl?}/{url?}/{pId?}"
@page "/{parent?}/{categoryUrl?}/{url?}/{suburl?}/{pId?}"
@page "/{parent?}/{categoryUrl?}/{url?}/{pId?}/{month:int?}/{year:int?}"  
@rendermode InteractiveAuto
```

**Code:**

```cs
[Parameter]
public string? url { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public string? suburl { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public string? parent { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public string? categoryUrl { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public string? pId { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public int? month { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public int? year { get; set; }
```

---

I then use `OnParametersSetAsync()` to create logic for what happens with the parameters.

The strange thing is that the auto generated stylesheet, *[project].styles.css*, is showing up as the parent parameter even when the url is on the baseUrl (https://localhost:7215/) and the parent parameter is empty (see attached image).

[image]

Why is this and how can it be fixed?

Comment: The issue you're encountering, where the auto-generated stylesheet name `[project].styles.css` appears as the `parent` parameter, is likely due to how Blazor processes the URL and matches it against the page route templates you've defined.By default, static files like CSS should be served directly by the server without going through the Blazor routing system. If the stylesheet request is somehow being intercepted by Blazor's router, make sure that your static files are correctly configured in the `Startup.cs` or `Program.cs` file, depending on your project setup.

Comment: make sure  Static files middleware registered before Blazor's server-side routing middleware.Check the `<base href="/" />` tag in your `_Host.cshtml` or `index.html` file.

Comment: I had the same problem. It looks like it related a page being home(starting) page.